# How can I set an e-mail's headers using /usr/bin/mail?

Tags: aix, sendmail, mail-command

I have a bunch of scripts on an IBM AIX server's crontab that call the mail command to send myself an e-mail, kinda like this:

```
$ mail -r myon@hakugyokuro.gk -s "Results for `hostname`" myon@hakugyokuro.gk <<EMAILCONTENT
Results of execution of command $COMMAND on `hostname`:

`cat /home/myon/executionresults.txt`
EMAILCONTENT
```

I intend to put a script that has something like this in a production environment, and as a result I'm trying to find a way to set mail headers using AIX's `/usr/bin/mail` so that the mails that come from Production arrive to my inbox as high priority. Migrating to Perl's Mail package would take a while, so it preferentially has to be with the standard mail command. I couldn't find an option to specify a mail header neither on `mail` nor on `sendmail` (which from what I gathered receives any option that mail can't already parse, in this case the `-r`).

Any idea of how to set headers this way?

**EDIT**: Thanks for the answer :3 here's how it worked, reworked so that it looks a bit more like the exhibit above:

```
$ sendmail -i -- myon@hakugyokuro.gk <<EMAILCONTENT
From: myon@hakugyokuro.gk
To: myon@hakugyokuro.gk
Importance: High
Subject: Results for `hostname`

Results of execution of command $COMMAND on `hostname`:

`cat /home/myon/executionresults.txt`
EMAILCONTENT
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Sendmail: Sending email with custom headers**

You can generate any header when you send using sendmail.
[ Sendmail fills missing **important** headers ]

```
FILE=/home/myon/executionresults.txt
HOSTNAME=`hostname`
cat - $FILE <<EMAILCONTENT | /usr/sbin/sendmail -i -- myon@hakugyokuro.gk
Subject: Results for $HOSTNAME
To: myon@hakugyokuro.gk

Results of execution of command $COMMAND on $HOSTANME:
------------------------------------------------------
EMAILCONTENT
```

P.S.
In such "no strict checks" script with generated dynamic headers **DO NOT** use `-t` command line option

Comment: Worked just fine with sendmail :3 methinks I'm going to use it for Production. Not like I need to change much.